# couldn't retrieve date from database

Tags: java, jsp

Hi,
I couldn't retrieve date from my database.
Here is my Code

```
String s1=" ",s2=" ",s3=" ",s4=" ",s5=" ",s6=" ",sdate=" ",edate=" ";
try
{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ocp2","root",     "");Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Statement st=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select courseid,coursename,sdate,edate,duration,fee from course     ");
ResultSetMetaData rd=rs.getMetaData();%>

<%  
while(rs.next())
{
    s1=rs.getString(1);
    s2=rs.getString(2);
    sdate=rs.getString(3);
    edate=rs.getString(4);
    DateFormat ff=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Format form=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    s3=form.format(ff.parse(sdate));
    s4=form.format(ff.parse(edate));
    s5=rs.getString(5);
    s6=rs.getString(6);%>
<tr>
<td><%=s1%></td>
<td><%=s2%></td>
<td><%=s3%></td>
<td><%=s4%></td>
<td><%=s5%></td>
<td><%=s6%></td>
</tr>
</tr>
```

Comment: Is there anything that you have tried? What is not working?

Comment: _I couldn't retrieve date from my database._ is not a valid statement . post what you get currently . even if you get errors

Comment: i just get table with empty sets

Comment: It doesn't show any error. But i am getting empty field sets as output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `s3=rs.getDate(1)` instead of getting a string and parsing it.

Comment: This is not an answer to this question !!!

Comment: With the small amount of details the OP has given us, one can only try and hive him hints...

Comment: @KisHanSarsecHaGajjar I would say that this is an answer to this question.

Comment: Yes I agree with you both, but is this ok to answer without knowing actual problem ?

Comment: I am getting empty fields as output. Is there anything I have to change?

Comment: @Vignesh Empty fields in every column? Does your DB have any data? Show the output and any error.

Comment: In my DB I have courseid,coursename,sdate,edate,duration,fee as 111,java,2013-12-12,2014-12-12,12,40000.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried this code and

```
java.sql.Date s3=rs.getDate(3);
java.sql.Date s4=rs.getDate(4);
```

Now i have got output.